# Revit API, Access Database, Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: api, memory, connection-string, revit

I recently upgraded from R16 to R19, but my addin throws an error I can't resolve.

When I try to read an access.mdb file, I get the "attempted to read or write protected memory" error.

I use the exact same code to connect to this file in an Acad2019 dll, there it works fine. Same happens on a different machine.

Windows 10, x64, .Net 4.7.2

The crash occurs in myConnection.open (Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.)

---

```
Imports System

Imports Autodesk.Revit.UI
Imports Autodesk.Revit.DB
    <Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)> _
Public Class Test
Implements IExternalCommand
Public Function Execute(ByVal revit As ExternalCommandData, ByRef message As String, _
ByVal elements As ElementSet) As Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result _
Implements IExternalCommand.Execute

Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection()

Dim strFileName As String = "C:\Users\X\Desktop\Revit 2019\Database.mdb"

If Not myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
myConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & "Data Source=" & strFileName

Try
myConnection.Open()
Catch ex As System.Exception
MsgBox("Error in reading database!")
End Try
End If
Return Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result.Succeeded

End Function
End Class
```

---

Any suggestions?

Gr, Piet

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I had Office 2016 installed, but also had to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable. After that the problem was gone.